# How to get Angular component selector value in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to get the `selector` name 'app-navigation' from inside the `ngOnInit` method.
How should I do it?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class Navigation implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("...what is my selector name?")
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class Navigation implements OnInit {
  constructor(elemRef: ElementRef) {
    const selectorName = elemRef.nativeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the selector contains capital letters?

Comment: For best practice with angular, your custom component selector has to be lower cased. See here: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#component-selectors

Comment: Not everyone's going to follow best practice. The answer is, there is no way to get the actual case of the selector in an HTML DOM tree. Accd. to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) the **returned tag name is always in the canonical upper-case form**.